# docker with no volume running, where does container system file store?

Tags: docker, volume

If I run a container with no volume specified, where does container system file store ?

- `docker run -it c_name i_name:tag`

when I run a container without volume, only container folder created in `/var/lib/docker/container`, but I If I create a large file in container file system, where does it stored on host? Because I want to know if it will cause occupying disk size issue.

Comment: Docker by default stores content in subdirectories of `/var/lib/docker`. On a Mac or Windows machine, this filesystem lives inside a Linux VM.

Comment: `dock info` and then look for `Docker Root Dir`. Or `docker inspect CONTAINER_NAME`

Comment: @larsks when I run a container without volume, only container folder created in `/var/lib/docker/container`, but I If I create a large file in container file system, where does it stored on host? Because I want to know if it will cause occupying disk issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The container's storage is composed of different layers, different layers will finally form a merged layer.

Let's make a small experiment next:

**1. Start a container & setup a new file:**

```
# docker run -idt --name trial debian /bin/bash
# docker exec -it trial /bin/bash
root@e6c2b6336753:/# echo "helloworld" > test.txt
root@e6c2b6336753:/# cat test.txt
helloworld
```

**2. Find the merged storage layer id:**

```
# docker inspect --format=" {{ .GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir }} " trial
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8f2e14d33448cb83e581b2950a69faa827a012904051c845abf550273196f90f/merged
```

Here, `8f2e14d33448cb83e581b2950a69faa827a012904051c845abf550273196f90f` is the layer id.

**3. Check layer:**

```
# cd /var/lib/docker/overlay2/8f2e14d33448cb83e581b2950a69faa827a012904051c845abf550273196f90f/merged
root@shlava:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8f2e14d33448cb83e581b2950a69faa827a012904051c845abf550273196f90f/merged# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  test.txt  tmp  usr  var
root@shlava:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8f2e14d33448cb83e581b2950a69faa827a012904051c845abf550273196f90f/merged# cat test.txt
helloworld
```

So, as a conclusion, you could see from above, the file system contents could be found in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/` with layer id as folder, you could check the disk there.

Comment: I have a new question: how to clean this `merged` layer elegantly?

Comment: There's more complex behavior for overlay fs in docker, so if you already find the big file with above method, just `exec` into the container to delete that big file. Suggest you don't directly delete the file system in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/`. If this is not your want, I don't know any elegant way to reset changes in container, you may raise new question to guys for good luck.

Comment: I find the `merged` dir not mount correctly when using docker-compose(with other service), I can't find `test.txt` in it.